# Oil burner runs for at least one cycle then safety locks out

Tags: furnace, boiler

I have an older Slant Fin Liberty oil furnace that safeties out sometime around 4 hours. It seems to be intermittent because I have seen it do more than one cycle. The recent history on it is about a month ago I changed the electrodes, nozzle and filter. It was running fine until a couple of days ago. I noticed pressing the reset caused it to kick right back on and appear to run normally for several hours.  What should I look for to troubleshoot this? We did get oil delivered. Maybe something with the fuel?

UPDATE 1:

I noticed this morning when I reset it, it fired then quit. I could hear the electrodes zapping. I had to reset it an addtional time after it quit. I'll pull the filter and check the flow later this morning.

UPDATE 2:

Added a video to demonstrate what I am dealing with. Please watch.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2T1W_llnz4

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Could you add a picture of the furnace's wiring diagram? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did your fuel run dry? There should be a flashing light near the rest button, count the flashes and this will be the error code. What type of burner do you have? What is the name of the controller with the reset button /flashing light?

Comment: https://www.beckettcorp.com/support/tech-bulletins/troubleshooting-the-cad-cell/

Comment: Hi guys, first of all thank you for the quick response. It being a holiday I really do appreciate the help. I edited the post to include a short video demonstrating the issue. I also included photos of the various components. Let me know if you spot anything. I am thinking the fuel should not come out milky. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2T1W_llnz4

Comment: How do you know the op has beckett parts? If it was the eye, then the the burner wouldn't make it past pre-purge. The fact that the burner works for a few hours, then it's not the eye.

Comment: You have air in the fuel/lines, you need to purge this air out of the system. Why is there air? Did you tighten the filter housing enough? Did you forget to remove old gasket so now there are 2? Is the bleeder screw on top of the filter tight and have a gasket? Are all fittings tight? The filter housing would be my first check.

Comment: @gunner - all good suggestions. I replaced the filter (although it did not look like it needed it). I checked to make sure I did not leave the old gasket in place (I didn't). Retightened everything and checked for leakes. On the input line before the filter there is a shutoff valve inline. Fully off is closed, fully tight opens the valve. One of the cupplings for that valve looks like it is letting air in. I can see it bubble the smallest amount. Anyway, this is a copper line. Can I unscrew it and wrap the thread in plumbers tape?

Comment: Can you try to tighten the fittings on the valve? No tape! If any gets loose and into system, it will screw up the pump and gun. Use something like Gasolia thread sealant. The valve you describe that works opposite of normal valves.... That is a special valve that is supposed to shutoff in high heat (a fire)

Comment: I will try to tighten it. I felt like it was as tight as I dared turn in on christmas eve. Not looking for a total disaster tognight with no hardware stores open.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share the additional steps I took to troubleshoot the issue and describe what was ultimately causing the issue. The problem comes down to a weak and short spark.  I was able to test the spark and witness that it was very quick and dim. I replaced the transformer and the protector relay. I likely did not have to replace the protector relay but figured it could not hurt. A retest with the new components showed a strong spark. Now I am back in business and should not have to worry about either of those components for years to come.

Comment: Glad you were able to lick the problem in the end!

Answer (score 0):

No tape! If any gets loose and into system, it will screw up the pump and gun. Use something like Gasolia thread sealant. The valve you describe that works opposite of normal valves.... That is a special valve that is supposed to shutoff in high heat (a fire)